# Exception: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, net.tcp, base-address

I've been struggling with reconfiguring a working service to add a netTcp endpoint.

The service is hosted on IIS 8.5

I've been getting the following exception:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the
>   endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes
>   are [http,https]

Stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches
>   scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered
>   base address schemes are [http,https].]
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri
>   relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses) +16994291
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement,
>   Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost) +1092
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader
>   configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement
>   serviceSection) +89
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration() +162
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses) +207    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +474
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +42
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +569
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1435
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +76
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +901
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service '/servicebus.svc' cannot be
>   activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp
>   for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address
>   schemes are [http,https]..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +624522
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +196075
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +166

```
  <services>
  <service name="Niloosoft.ServiceBus" behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationAndAuthorizationSecurity">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7213"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

    <endpoint
      address="secureBus"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
      contract="Niloosoft.IServiceBus" />
    <endpoint
      address="tcpBus"
      binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="ServiceBusTcpBinding"
      contract="Niloosoft.IServiceBus" />
    <endpoint
     address="tcpMex"
     binding="mexTcpBinding"
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint
      address="mex"
      binding="mexHttpsBinding"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The binding configurations seem to work well for other services but I may be missing something else.

IIS has binding configuration for each service, I added a tcp binding there with *:7213 address.

Any suggestions, ideas as to what I'm missing? I went through a lot of different posts to see if perhaps I made an error somewhere.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to add and enable net.tcp binding in IIS.  Read this:  https://rohitguptablog.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/configuring-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding/

Comment: The article was very helpful, although the IIS wasn't the problem, the configurations were off. thanks!  EDIT: for those interested in what went wrong  here, it was the httpgetenabled=true that causes the issue. it needs to be set to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the configuration HttpGetEnabled was set to true, it is necessary to set it to false if your webservice should accept HTTPS.